# How to get all approval process using metadata APIs

Tags: metadata-api

I want to fetch all(active and inactive) approval process.
I wanted to use metadata APIs, but I do not know how to design the request payload to get all the approval process.

Is there documentation present or any methods to create Metadata API payload?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

There is an in-depth [Metadata API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_intro.htm).

It's most common to use the Metadata API through a [ZIP-based deploy and retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/file_based_zip_file.htm), which uses a `package.xml` manifest to define the scope of components to affect. There are both REST- and SOAP-based endpoints available.

You can find details of the hundreds of available metadata types and their unique behaviors in the [Metadata Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm) section of the guide. See [Approval Process](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_approvalprocess.htm). Since it states

> Use the wildcard character * (asterisk) in the package.xml manifest file to retrieve all approval processes for all objects

you can use a `package.xml` manifest like this with a retrieval to retrieve all components:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApprovalProcess</name>
    </types>
    <version>51.0</version>
</Package>
```

Note that the Salesforce CLI, Workbench, and many other common tools are already Metadata API clients, so you may not need to build your own client or payload beyond defining the manifest.